# UL LI Current INDEX

Tags: html-lists

if i was coding like as below...

how do i get the currennt LI index ??

JSP

```
    <c:forEach var="list" items="${list}">
      <ul id="bbs">
         <li><a>item1</a></li>
         <li class="tmpClick"><a>item2</a></li>
         <li><a>item3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </foreach>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 jq('.tmpClick').click(function() {
    console.log( "log " +jq(this).index() ) ;
 });
//-->
</script>
```

Ex) 
- HTML TAG

```
<ul id="bbs">
  <li><a>item1</a></li>
  <li class="tmpClick"><a>item2</a></li>
  <li><a>item3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="bbs">
  <li><a>item1</a></li>
  <li class="tmpClick"><a>item2</a></li>
  <li><a>item3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="bbs">
  <li><a>item1</a></li>
  <li class="tmpClick"><a>item2</a></li>
  <li><a>item3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="bbs">
  <li><a>item1</a></li>
  <li class="tmpClick"><a>item2</a></li>
  <li><a>item3</a></li>
</ul>
.
.
.
.
```

- RESULT

IDX | TITLE | RECOMMEND

1   item1    1

2   item2    2

3   item3    3

4   item4    4

.

.

.

firefox log

log 1

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the status variable.

```
<c:forEach var="foo" items="${list}" varStatus="status">  
  <option value="${status.count}"></option>  
</c:forEach>
```

To clarify:

- `${status.index}` starts counting at 0
- `${status.count}` starts counting at 1

Comment: you mean... i have to make each html ID???  ( id="bbs1" ... id="bbs2" ... id="bbs3" .... ) like this ???

Comment: Yes, thats a quick way to get the indices for your example.  You shouldn't be restricted to only setting the ID attribute; you can use any attribute and even create your own.

Another method would be to get the parent object, and iterate over the other 'li' tags until you get back to the original tag.